# Incremental Appending Value in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Is there a way in SSIS to go through a certain column in a table and to collect incrementally the values for each row in this column and to finally insert the final value to a second field or parameter?

Is it possible to do it with no external code? only within SSIS tasks?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean?    Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Add a variable to hold the value
2. Add a script component to the dataflow
3. Add the code below to the script task, modifying references to the correct column and variable name:

   ```
   int count = 0;

   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) 
   {
       count = Row.count + count;
   }

   public override void PostExecute()
   {
       base.PostExecute();
       Variables.MyCount = count;
   }
   ```